# Feynman Volume 1 Question about pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

I was reading the book, and I found this:
[image]

So my question is this: why the number of collisions increase with the piston in the same proportion as the area was increased? Can someone please clarify this to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the number of molecules *per unit volume* is defined as constant. In other words, it's like adding another *identical* complete piston/cylinder/gas system next to the first one, and concluding that the total number of collisions for the two pistons (twice the total area now) is exactly twice the number for just one. This works for any proportion.

Comment: So it means that the number of molecules increased too? So it's like if the density increases twice?

Comment: No. Density is the same. There are more collisions during a given time because the area is greater.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand it, I think I'm missing something. I thought that if the area increased there would be less collisions . But I can't understand why there are more collisions. So when you say, "Because the number of molecules per unit volumeis defined as constant. In other words, it's like adding another identical complete piston/cylinder/gas system next to the first one " it also means that the same identical amount of molecules per unit volume is added to total system, which includes the two systems? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Think of it this way: if the number of collisions in one second on the left half of the piston is x, then the number of collisions on the right half is also x. Therefore the number of collisions per second on the whole piston, which is twice the area of half, is 2x.

Comment: So it means it's just a logical fact that if we increase the area obviously the number of collisions will increase? Even though the number of molecules remain constant?

Comment: The number of molecules PER CUBIC CENTIMETER.

Comment: Ok Tom, can you please explain me that. I really don't know a lot about physics or math. But I started to read Feynman physics volume 1 book . Can you explain me why is so important the fact that the number of molecules are per cubic centimeter. When I think of that I see that the number of molecules increased as the area increased even the book says that the molecules are constant.

Comment: The book does NOT say "keep the number of molecules constant", it says "...keep the number of molecules per cubic centimeter the same..." That is critical. Do you see the difference? The number of molecules of air in your kitchen is more than the number of molecules of air in your closet, but the number of molecules *per cubic centimeter* is the same. It's basically the same as saying the *density* of air is the same in the kitchen and the closet (for the same temperature).

Comment: So the number of molecules increased but the density remains the same since the volume increased too right?

Comment: Yes. BUT, you can also imagine a situation where you change the *shape* of the cylinder (shorter and fatter) so the total volume is the same, *and* the number of molecules is the same, *and* the density is the same, *but* the area of the piston is greater, *and so is the number of collisions*. SO, if the density remains constant: when the area increases so does the number of collisions per second (at the same temperature)

Comment: Ok Tom B. Thanks for your explanations, I finally got it.